# apply and call a session in different controllers

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, authentication

I am using zend framework. I have built a simple login screen. when the user logs in, I want to set a session and then in the init function of the member area controller its meant to check for the session and grant access, else, redirect to login screen.

I have set my login controller like so, this check the username and password and sets the session:

```
if (isset($_POST['loginSubmit']) && $form->isValid($_POST)){
            $inputtedUsername = $_POST['username'];
            $inputtedPassword = $_POST['password'];
            if ($inputtedUsername == $username && $inputtedPassword == $password) {
                $loggedIn = new Zend_Session_Namespace('loggedIn');
                $loggedIn->success;
                $this->_forward('index', 'home');
            } else {
                echo 'invalid';
            }
        }
```

I have a home controller, which only logged in users should be able to see, so in the innit function I have:
$loggedIn = new Zend_Session_Namespace('loggedIn');

```
if (isset($loggedIn->success)) {
            echo 'success';
        }else{
            $url = $this->view->url(array(
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action' => 'index'));
            header('Location:' . $url);
        }
    }
```

when i log in, using the correct credentials, it redirects me to login screen as stated in the else function.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your use of Zend_Session_Namespace is incomplete (you never assigned a value to the namespace):

```
$loggedIn = new Zend_Session_Namespace('loggedIn');//here you created a namespace
$loggedIn->success;//here you created a key in that namespace with no value
```

The way your code seems to be structured any value assigned to `$loggedIn->success` would return true, so maybe try :

```
$loggedIn = new Zend_Session_Namespace('loggedIn');//here you created a namespace
$loggedIn->success = true;
```

While this might fix your current issue, I want to suggest you take a look at two Zend components that can really help with authentication and authorization.

The first is [Zend_Auth](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.auth.introduction.html), a component that deals with application authentication and will also help handle user session persistence. [Rob Allen has a tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-auth-tutorial/) to help get you started.

The second is [Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.acl.introduction.html), The Access Control List component, deals with authorization, who has access to what. [A place to start with Zend_Acl](http://zendguru.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/zend-framework-acl-with-example/)